# Error 412 when playing audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, ogg

Whenever I try to play an ogg-type audio, which is longer than 3 minutes, I get the status 412 (Precondition Failed)

---

Headers:

```
General : 

Request URL:http://192.168.100.253/tmp/1488371549.857-093236-41846255-3400.ogg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:412 Precondition Failed
Remote Address:192.168.100.253:80


Response Headers:

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:audio/ogg
Date:Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:48:45 GMT
ETag:W/"9fb0d-18b3e3-549aeec845b72"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:48:44 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22

Request Headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:kwebmonitor-columns-filter=channel%2Csignaling%2Cstatus%2Cdetails%2CdialNumber%2CcallDuration%2CaverageTimeCalls%2Cinbound%2Coutbound%2Csim_card%2Coper%2Cstrength%2Coptions; PPA_ID=2vo89lpmfmrvms6oojftl3p6r4; webfx-tree-cookie-persistence=wfxt-4+wfxt-6+wfxt-8+wfxt-22+wfxt-24+wfxt-26;     session_id_admanager=192.168.100.197-31cd334d-1263-4c8a-aaac-44d7383cbec9
Host:192.168.100.253
If-Match:W/"9fb0d-18b3e3-549aeec845b72"
Range:bytes=1540096-
Referer:http://192.168.100.253:81/bilhetes/busca_chamadas
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

---

Code example :

> ```
> <audio controls>
>      <source src="PATH_TO_AUDIO" type="audio/ogg">
>      Your browser dont support this plugin!
> </audio>
> ```

---

My browser is Google chrome v.55

Comment: Why is `Content-Length` of response `0`?

Comment: this may help (etag/if-match): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620203/http-status-412-precondition-failed-and-database-versioning#3628559